# How should I display quiz questions against results table?

Tags: php, game-engine

I've a simple query that selects all quizzes from DB.

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM quizz WHERE quizz_level = $level");
```

To display this result, I do simple `foreach`.

I also have a results table where I save outcome of the quizz

```
result_id, user_id, quizz_id, result_value
```

Now I'd like to modify original foreach and if result exist for spceific user for specific quizz, mark it differently (as answered).

I intend to do following, SELECT results table and grab all quizz_id's for specific user. Put this into an array. And while doing original foreach to display quizz questions, match it against keys in results array.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Can it be done via mysql sub-query?

p.s. probably my worst title ever for the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT q.*,case when r.user_id = $user_id then 1 else 0 end case as answered
FROM quizz q
inner join results r on q.quizz_id = r.quizz_id
 WHERE q.quizz_level = $level
```

and then filter on answered on your php code

EDIT

I've changed the left outer to inner as it doesn't make sense the left outer. Also changed the columns of the join to quizz_id

The select is bringing all the records from the table quizz (q.*) and with the inner join is linking to the results table on the quizz_id columns.

Then on the select part I use case to check if the user_id is the one you are looking for

```
 case when r.user_id = $user_id then 1 else 0 end case as answered
```

Then the recorset will have all the quizz table columns plus a column called answered where if the value is 1 that quizz was answered by the user_id and if its 0 then it wasn't answered by the user_id.

Comment: How does it understand that we are talking about r results table? I'm having hard time following what is happening here :) mind explaining?

Comment: check my edit, maybe I am missing somethins. If it is not clear please include both table structures in your post.